# Issue with Move to iOS android app to migrate to iphone

Tags: migration, android, ios, migration-assistant

I'm trying to migrate some data from an old Samsung phone running Android 4 to an iPhone 5s running iOS11.

The issue I'm stuck with is that when I setup the iphone and select move data from android, it gives me a 6 digit code, but on the Android device is expecting a 10 digit code.

Is there anything that can be done?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a 4 digit passcode on your iPhone? Its the 4 digits you put in your phone once you turn it on and want to get into the iPhone.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson I do have a 4 digit pass on the iphone but it's already unlocked. Do I still have to enter both the pass and the 6 digits?

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a solution in meanwhile.
Anyway I faced the some problem yesterday and I even contact Apple to get some information. They said me that the version installed in my new brand iPhone XS is now accepting just 6 digits instead the 10 Android was requesting me. And proposed me to use another app called MCBackup which is a contact transfer and save app for android and iOS.

Then I start to think a bit. First I tried the current version of Move to iOS which didn't run on my android. So I started to look into a older version what I got this morning. The one I found was from 2018 called Move to iOS 2.10.0 (com.apple.movetoios_2.10.0-2100_minAPI14(armeabi)(nodpi) and it can be downloaded at https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/apple-inc/move-to-ios/move-to-ios-2-10-0-release/#downloads.

Please assure that this is the version, older ones (1.57 and 1.59) do not work, I tried.

I hope I could help some other who intent to migrate all Android's data to the new iPhone...

Answer (score -1):

Try entering both the 6 digit code and then follow it with your passcode that you use on the iPhone. That should allow it to accept and migrate the data.

Comment: doesn't work. Tried putting the code first and after the 6 digit code, tried disabling the 4 digit code in the iphone and still asks for a 10 digit code in the android device and still can't connect.

Comment: Go to "settings"
Then go to "Touch ID & Passcode"
type in your current passcode
then click on "change passcode"
type in your current passcode again
click on passcode options
click on custom numeric code and then create a 10 digit code.

Comment: Doesn't work, iOS only gives you the option to move from Android once you are setting up the device. So you can't go into settings and try again.

Comment: Event then I tried and still doesn't work

Comment: Right so you'll have to erase the iPhone to Move from Android.

Comment: If you've already put stuff on the iPhone try to save it on the PC or some where else until its setup properly.

Comment: The iphone was already reset and clean. The phone passcode and the Move to iOS app code number are different things. Your solution didn't work